# scikit learn word co-occurrence matrix

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to get a word co-occurrence matrix from a set of text documents. Instead of creating the matrices and handling them myself, I was wondering if there is a method in scikit learn to get a word co-occurrence matrix from a list of documents?

Any pointers to the relevant class will be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, what is the output format? Is it a matrix where each entry (i, j) is co-occurence count of words i and j?